# RewriteRule и редирект

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Ссылка `http://mysite.com/category/page`.

Как написать RewriteRule, чтобы убрать category?

Ну т.е. если в браузер ввести `http://mysite.com/page`, то попадало на тот же `http://mysite.com/category/page`, но без category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая часть вопроса элементарна:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/$1 [L,QSA]
```

А, вот, как сделать, чтобы при наборе `http://mysite.com/category/page` он превращал эту строку в  `http://mysite.com/page` - это я бы тоже был рад узнать.
Только два момента:
1) Без использования маячков, типа:

```
http://mysite.com/page?q=afterBuild
```

2) Средствами mod_rewrite

Comment: при наборе http://mysite.com/category/page оно должно остаться, но при наборе http://mysite.com/page должен произойти как бы "невидимый редирект" на category/page, но чтобы в браузере так и осталось page.